# Adding selected options to state array reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I am working on an ecommerce application

I am using react-select to select multi category

I want to get the value selected by the use and add it to the state category

```
const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const AddProductModal = ({addOpenProductModal, setAddOpenProductModal}) => {

const [category, setCategory] = useState({
        category: []
    })
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        // let {label, value} = e.target;
        console.log(e);
        // setCategory({ category: [...category, 'new value'] })
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <Select
          onChange={handleChange}
          isMulti
          name="categories"
          options={options} />
        </div>
    )

}

export default AddProductModal
```

Comment: what is the value of console.log(e); ?

Comment: also try with - event.target.value

Comment: @MukulSharma it is giving me array of the selected value